\documentclass not working when inside \input
When I place my \documentclass command inside my preamble.tex file (which I am importing into the main.tex file using \input), my compliation fails with the error *** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
I also get the following message (on Overleaf):
No PDF
This compile didn’t produce a PDF. This can happen if:
-There is an unrecoverable LaTeX error. If there are LaTeX errors shown below or in the raw logs, please try to fix them and compile again.
-The document environment contains no content. If it’s empty, please add some content and compile again.
-This project contains a file called output.pdf. If that file exists, please rename it and compile again.

Is it just a case of placing the \documentclass command directly in main.tex, or is there a workaround?

if you obfuscate your source too much overleaf can not guess which is the main file and you need to set it explicitly in the sidebar menu

in particular if you have a .tex file with \documentclass that is assumed to be the main file so overleaf will be running latex on preamble.tex and not seeing the end of document. You can set the main, but far simpler is to put documentclass in the main document.

Thanks David. It seems that the 'Main document' setting is for main.tex but maybe the placement of \documentclass is overwriting that? I'll just place it back into the main document, as you said it's easier.

@DavidCarlisle Looks like an answer ...

I changed the 'Main document' setting to something else and then back to main, and it now seems to work

This is more an overleaf problem than a general LaTeX problem. Therefore you should better asked the overleaf staff.

This is an overleaf setting issue rather than anything under latex control.
If you have multiple .tex files in your project overleaf needs to decide which are top level files on which you can run latex and which are file input into a main document.  Its default guess if a single file has \documentclass is that that is the main file.
So either you need to move \documentclass to the main file (that's what I would do as it is the more natural markup) or you can use the setting in the left sidebar of your Overleaf project to specify a different file as the main document.
